# img only rotates on 2nd click and after

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rotation

So I'm really poor at jQuery/everything and I have an img that should be rotating while toggling at the same time except that on the first click it does NOT rotate but still toggles and every click from there on out it rotates and toggles, but then the img is backwards!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#center").hide();
    $("div.center").hide();
    $("img.plath.intro").hide();
    $("#footer").hide();
    $("div.left").hide();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var angle = 0;
    $("img.uparrowimg").click(function(){
        $(this).rotate({
            bind:{
                click: function(){
                    angle +=180;
                    $(this).rotate({animateTo:angle,easing: $.easing.easeInOutExpo })
                }
            }
        });
        $("#center").toggle(1000);
        $("#menu").toggle(1000);
        $("#footer").toggle(1000);
        $("img.plath.intro").toggle(1000);
        $("div.center").toggle(1000);
        $("div.left").toggle(1000);
        $("#divtext").hide();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#divtext").hide();
    $("img.PlathIntro").click(function(){
        $("#divtext").fadeIn(3000);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what are you using for `$.rotate()`? Are using a plugin?

Comment: BTW You can select many things at once `$("#center, #menu, #footer, #etc").toggle(1000);`

Comment: Sorry, yeah I'm using a jQueryRotate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have bound the click function inside another, so it's not ready the first time you click - it's set up on first click.

```
$("img.uparrowimg").click(function(){ // <-- waiting for a click
    $(this).rotate({
        bind:{
            click: function(){ // <-- this is bound when that first click occurs
```

You need to separate the setting up of rotate from the click event. You can chain the two things like this

```
    $("img.uparrowimg").rotate({
        bind:{
            click: function(){
                angle +=180;
                $(this).rotate({animateTo:angle,easing: $.easing.easeInOutExpo })
            }
        }
    }).click(function(){
        $("#center").toggle(1000);
        $("#menu").toggle(1000);
        $("#footer").toggle(1000);
        $("img.plath.intro").toggle(1000);
        $("div.center").toggle(1000);
        $("div.left").toggle(1000);
        $("#divtext").hide();
    });
```

By the way you can select many things at once

```
$("#center, #menu, #footer, img.plath.intro, div.center, div.left").toggle(1000);
```

Or you could use a class and add that class to all those elements in HTML

```
<div id="menu" class="toggles">...</div>
<div id="footer" class="toggles">...</div>

$(".toggles").toggle(1000);
```

Comment: Ok so that fixed the rotation, but now the toggles don't work at all?

Comment: Your console should have shown you the syntax error. I copied a `});` too many into the code above.

Comment: Try again, the brackets are now balanced

Comment: That was worse. With that now, everything is showing right away, no toggle and no rotation.

Comment: fixed it! I moved the .click with the toggles out one level and it worked. Thank you so much!